# Java and ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    package test.arraylist;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TestArraylist {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    static int how_many;  
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            menu();
        }
        public static void menu()
        {
            System.out.println("1.L2C");
            System.out.println("2.M2R");

            int menu = keyboard.nextInt();keyboard.nextLine();
            switch (menu){
                case 1:

                    NewClass l2c = new NewClass();
                    System.out.println("How many:");
                    how_many = keyboard.nextInt();keyboard.nextLine();
                    for (int i=0;i<how_many;i++){
                    System.out.println("Insert values:");
                    l2c.l2c.add(keyboard.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("values:"+l2c.getL2c());
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:

                    NewClass r2p = new NewClass();
                    System.out.println("How many:");
                    how_many = keyboard.nextInt();keyboard.nextLine();
                    for (int i=0;i<how_many;i++){
                    System.out.println("Insert values:");
                    r2p.r2p.add(keyboard.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("values:"+r2p.getR2p());
                    }
                    break;


            }


        }
    public static void seats(){
        System.out.println("values:"+r2p.getR2p()); // Error
        System.out.println("values:"+l2p.getR2p()); // Error 
    }

    }
```

**---------------------------CLASS-----------------------**

```
package test.arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NewClass {

      ArrayList<String> l2c = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<String> r2p = new ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<String> getL2c() {
        return l2c;
    }

    public void setL2c(ArrayList<String> l2c) {
        this.l2c = l2c;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getR2p() {
        return r2p;
    }

    public void setR2p(ArrayList<String> r2p) {
        this.r2p = r2p;
    }



}
```

I'm in java for only 2 weeks
In a few words, I'm going to explain what I'm trying to do.

I am creating an `ArrayList`, after this user is entering
values to `Arraylist`.
Once everything is done, I want to access data from another method and to make some math operations, I realized that I should use some sort of return, I have tried to do this, but it does not work.

I am definitely doing something wrong.Pls help to sort this out.I spent 2 days on this.

Comment: Your variables only have scope in their respective `case` blocks. You need to fix that.

Comment: what is going wrong? if you're just starting with java for two weeks now, you may want to check the very basics before jumping to collections.

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: you cannot make a static reference to non-static field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you need is the composition of the `NewClass` into your Main class i.e.`TestArraylist` , Read composition in java [composition-in-java-example](https://www.journaldev.com/1325/composition-in-java-example)

Now your code should be like this,

```
  public class TestArraylist {
   static NewClass newClass = new NewClass(); 
 ---------
 --------
     public static void menu(){

            case 1:
                ArrayList<String> l2c = newClass.getL2c(); //this way you can access the data
                System.out.println("How many:");
                how_many = keyboard.nextInt();keyboard.nextLine();
                for (int i=0;i<how_many;i++){
                System.out.println("Insert values:");
                l2c.add(keyboard.nextLine()); //here you need only the instance variable to add the data into the arraylist.
                System.out.println("values:"+l2c.toString()); //to print the data
                }
                break;
    //Same way you should modify the case2 as well.
            case 2:

                ArrayList<String> r2p = newClass.getR2p();
                System.out.println("How many:");
                how_many = keyboard.nextInt();keyboard.nextLine();
                for (int i=0;i<how_many;i++){
                System.out.println("Insert values:");
                r2p.add(keyboard.nextLine());
                System.out.println("values:"+r2p.toString());
                }
                break;
```

Now that composite object will be accesible in you below method because we have declared it static.

`public static void seats(){
        System.out.println("values:"+newClass.getR2p()); // not throw any error
        System.out.println("values:"+newClass.getR2p()); // not throw any error
    }`

Also your `Newclass` should be defined like this,

```
public class NewClass {
private ArrayList<String> l2c = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> r2p = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getL2c() {
    return l2c;
}

public void setL2c(ArrayList<String> l2c) {
    this.l2c = l2c;
}

public ArrayList<String> getR2p() {
    return r2p;
}

public void setR2p(ArrayList<String> r2p) {
    this.r2p = r2p;
}
}
```

There are many things to be corrected but as of now to make your programm work , this should suffice.

Comment: This would not work, as static variables can not be declared within a method body; they **must** be declared within the root of the class itself. Also, a `private` modifier would be a good approach, unless the access needed to be less strict.

Comment: that outside method body @bradely, its a class level variable.

Comment: @Rishal dev singh , Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `seats()`, you will have an error because those variables are not declared within the proper scope. To make `r2p` and `l2c` available within that method, move the variable declarations outside of the method (below the class declaration, before `main()`) with the initializer `private static NewClass newClass;`. Feel free to assign a value as needed, or employ optionals (but considering you’ve only been doing Java for 2 weeks, stay away from optionals; just make sure you assign a value).

Edit: Use `static` modifier on the variables, since you’re accessing from a static context.

Comment: still he have to change the method to public otherwise he can't access varaibles

Comment: @Yuuuucef As long as he’s staying within the same class, he can. Or he can create a getter, that’s a safer approach instead of hard-coding a reference.

Comment: @VitalIliic i did test it IDE give non-static varaible cannot b referenced from a static context :/

Comment: @Yuuuucef I updated the original post, I realized that the `static` keyword had to be added; I’m on my phone, no access to IntelliJ.

Comment: @VitalIliic My apologies again, it would be more effective to just declare one instance of `NewClass` due to the fact that it contains `l2c` and `r2p` in it; no need for unnecessary variables.